# memory operations behind file handling operations in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, file-handling

`ifstream f1;
f1.open("file1.txt");`
In the above code snippet, is the entire "file1.txt" loaded into the RAM from auxiliary memory, or is it only after I implement some operations like `f1 >> data` does this transfer takes place?

Answer (score 2):

you only create a handler. Reading the data is what loads the file into memory